# Explicitly dereferencing a pointer in C++

Tags: visual-c++, klocwork

I am actually working on some changes to my application and klocwork keeps complaining me about one issue:

I have a struct, say

```
Struct A
{
  long x;
  bool b;
}
```

I have a pointer and it is assigned a return value from another function:

```
A* z= (A*) function.get();

if(!z->x)
{
  z->x= somevalue;
}
```

The klocwork keeps pointing to `if(!z->x)`, saying that z is explicitly dereferenced.

Although my application works fine now, will it affect my application in a drastic way in future?

Comment: What happens in `function`?

Comment: Actually that function deals with critical section and only returns a value when it is done in the critical section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check whether z is non-null before deferencing z and checking for z->x.

```
 if(z && !z->k)
     ...
```